# Are there any inherently non-partitionable datasets?

Tags: partitioning, scalability

Are there any practical datasets that, *by their nature*, cannot be partitioned in any practical way?

I am wondering about this because such datasets would be ill-suited to scaling out on commodity hardware and databases containing such data could be forced to scale up on expensive servers, at great cost.

**Edit:** by *nature*, I mean that the lack of partitionability is a consequence of the data and of the queries that must be made against it, rather than poor design choices.

Comment: Any data set which only contains values which are very similar, or has many identical values wouldn't partition very well (e.g., Y/N, 1/0, True/False, NULL/NOTNULL flags).